# SQL Server queries run fast against prod but not the replication DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Experienced a 4 min slow down when running reports against SQL Server replication database, specifically created to run reports against.

Prod runs fine, replication use to run in < 1, now takes 4 minutes.

We did two things prior to slowdown:

- Truncate log file from 400gb to 100mb
- re-created replication job after new data was not happening on Monday

The items were working Friday. From what I can see it the replication is a smaller database as we dont use all the data in prod for reports. I think it might be related to the execution plan being recreated when the new replication job was created but seems very odd, any idea guys?

Comment: For a particular query? compare execution plans between that query and the one that runs fast on prod

Comment: Are the two servers setup exactly the same? Same versions of SQL Server? Same editions of SQL server? Same storage volume types and IOPS? Same amount of RAM (and MaxMemory settings)? Same MAXDOP settings? Are the covering indexes the same on both databases? Same compatibility_level setting on both databases - this has definite effects on query planner and execution plans?

Comment: Also it appears to randomly be dropping permissions for the user account to execute some sps, and access some tables. Adding the specific permissions to the objects (directly) seems to get the error to go away, but the fear is it will continue to lose those and be slow regardless. I use shared dataset, data sources, and inherited this sql server that has ssrs installed on the same server, gross i know. Thresholds all look good on the vm though, suprisingly.

Comment: VM... it's not ESXi, is it? Newer versions might be better but 5.x series had horrible IO quotas that could not be properly controlled.

Comment: Sadly both dbs are on the same server, running the same version. Looking at the execution plan shows a this difference, 11b in prod (bigger db) 127b on replication db. Which seems really odd to me.

Comment: Yep its esxi, fml

Comment: Side note: Just a tip of the hat to all of you sql junkies being online and available to ask questions and provide insight. I love this community and you guys are the real mvps.

Comment: Are they on the same data store? I've seen SQL perform reasonably on VMFS5, for example, but be horrible on VMFS3 (or VMFS3 that was upgraded because it never truly upgrades).

Comment: So i isolated it to the same dbs on the same server from literally untangling the tangled sql christmas lights from our prior "dba", and they are located on the same data store. I originally though it came from data retrieval on the ssrs server but the deeper dive shows the same issues running the report query directly from the server its housed on. (Even performed  a restore on the ssrs server in a sandbox to validate the issues werent with the ssrs instance)

Comment: Is there a way to leverage the execution plan running the query in prod to the replication server? And is it even a good idea?

Comment: Big ups to the editor for making the request easier to read, thank you, ill try to keep this format in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your replicated database doesn't have the same indexes as the primary database. Check that primary key constraints are being replicated (in the article properties), and check that indexes are being replicated.

Take a look at all the indexes and keys in the replicated database and compare them to the source database. It sounds highly likely that they're different.

Comment: i will check this today and get back to you. I Would assume the same as the report (replication) DB actually should contain less information, thus less page indexes. Do you believe an extended delay by from > 1 to 4 minutes could be attributed from this particularly or is this just part of a bigger problem? Thank you for the suggestion by the way.

Comment: This was the solution. The new replication job spun up by my dev did not stipulate the indexes from the production instance. Rebuilding manually did take place but then the indexes did not match. Re-running the replication job with including the indexes specifically resolved the issue. You GUYS ARE MY HERO!!!!